# Does the size of a file system cluster have to be even bytes?

Tags: filesystems, cluster

Basically, could we have a file system with odd byte size clusters? Why is everything even? Thanks

Comment: I guess it's usually 2^n, but don't know if that is a necessity

Comment: When you have a width and you need to know the number of "blocks" it takes, if it's a power of two, the operation is a right shift operation: the most basic operation a CPU can perform. If it's not a power of two, the operation is a division: a very complex operation. Same for the other way (but less difficult for constants): left shift vs multiplication

Comment: @A.B it’s not quite as simple as that, you’d need to shift with carry to round up.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes my comment isn't complete (eg: if it's not exactly divisible, must add one block etc.)

Comment: @A.B right, I imagined you were aware of that, I just wanted to qualify the “most basic operation” for other readers — yes, shifting is one of the most basic operations, but the calculation of the number of blocks required involves a little more ;-). (And shifting with carry is probably not the most efficient; one could rotate right and check the top bits after the operation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, it would be possible to implement a file system with clusters of any size; but ultimately, file systems are constructed on top of something else (typically storage, a network …). Disks in particular provide interfaces which handle storage with a granularity of 512 or 4096 bytes (in some cases, with an additional 8 or 16 bytes for integrity); using cluster sizes which aren’t multiples of these sizes would be extremely inefficient.

Going in the other direction, file systems work with memory, and memory is also managed with a power-of-two granularity, *e.g.* 4KiB, 1MiB, etc. A file system with clusters which don’t fit into that would also be inefficient, and clusters larger than memory pages present problems of their own (see for example [the Ext2 file system](https://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html), which supports 8KiB blocks on Alpha systems with 8KiB memory pages, but only 4KiB blocks on 32-bit x86 systems with 4KiB pages).